# How to alternate colors of v-list rows in vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

How would be the best way to archive a result v-list-item rows alternate their respective background colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this effect using CSS `nth-child` selectors with even and odd values. You might need to override the Vuetify theme colors. Consider specifyng a class on the parent list to prevent all lists in your app/component from being affected. There is no Vuetify native solution as far as I can see from the documentation.

```css
.v-list-item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CCC
}

.v-list-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFF
}
```